# How to add font awesome icon dynamically into Angular table (which is filled with objects)

Tags: angular, html-table, expression, font-awesome, ngfor

I fill a table dynamically with *ngFor:

```
<tr *ngFor="let device of devices">
    <td></td>
    <td>{{device.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

I'd like to add dynamically an FontAwesome icon into the empty  tag. How do I do this? (want to save the icon into the device object).

Comment: You should be storing the font-awesome class in the object.

Comment: Thanks a lot, worked great: <td><i class="{{device.icon}}"></i> {{device.name}}</td>